# Combining Generics and Templates in C++/CLI

Tags: c++, templates, generics, c++-cli

I am currently new to `C++/CLI` and as an exercise I want to make custom array classes with the unmanaged code. I made a class in a `C++` dll and named it `CustomArray`. It is currently blank only the template and constructor stuff exist. I've put it inside of `Unmanaged` namespace. Here's the full code for `CustomArray` class :-

```cpp
namespace Unmanaged
{
    template <typename T>
    class CustomArray
    {
        private:
            T* m_Data;

        public:
            CustomArray(int size)
            {

            }
    };
}
```

I also have a managed ref class called `CustomArray` in a `C++/CLI` console app. I want to make it use the templated `CustomArray` class of unmanaged code. Here's the full code for `CustomArray` class inside the `Managed` namespace :-

```cpp
namespace Managed
{
    generic <typename T>
    public ref class CustomArray
    {
        private:
            Unmanaged::CustomArray<T>* array;

        public:
            CustomArray(int size)
            {
                
            }
    };
}
```

But here I get the error at the line where I declare/define the `Unmanaged::CustomArray<T>*`. Visual Studio says `A template argument may not reference a generic type parameter`. I don't know what is happening here as I said earlier I am new to `C++/CLI`. If someone knows, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

`C++` templates are compile time, so all information to construct a "templated" class/method must be available at compile time.

`C++/CLI` generics are runtime, that is generic class/method can be created at a runtime.

Your generic class simply cannot create an arbitrary template class at a runtime (neither a pointer to an object of template class).

Reference: [Generics and Templates (C++/CLI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/generics-and-templates-visual-cpp?view=msvc-160) from Microsoft.

Please note that the purpose of `C++/CLI` is to provide interoperability between native and .NET code, and it's better to avoid implementing a business logic in `C++/CLI`.